# Encrypt/decrypt content in database for multiple users

Tags: php, mysql, encryption

Usual scenario is that someone wants to store and encrypt data which will be later available (readable) only by him. But here I want to encrypt (plain and binary (BLOB)) data in my MySQL database so that someone gaining direct access to the database cannot read this data. But in this scenario all registered users should be able to insert (encrypt) data for all others and vice versa all registered users should be able to read (decrypt) data inserted and encrypted by others.

So, the point of my question is how users of web application built above MySQL database will share the same key for encryption/decryption of data in db? Each user must be able to encrypt data that others will be able to decrypt.

Answer (score 0):

This question is a little bit abstract, and maybe I will miss some important point but...

As of myself, I would just encrypt/decrypt at application level. So from your database point of view, encrypted data are just `TEXT` or `BLOG` columns, depending the output of your encryption algorithm.

---

An other option would be to use [MySQL standard encryption functions](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/encryption-functions.html) to encrypt data while storing them and decrypt them while accessing. I less favor that solution since non-encrypted data will travel on the network to/from the DB server.

---

This is probably obvious, but keep in mind you won't be able to search or sort on encrypted data.

Comment: Hi Sylvain, the point of my question is how users of web application built above MySQL database will share the same key for encryption/decryption of data in db? Each user must be able to encrypt data that others will be able to decrypt.

Comment: @sbrbot As I tried to explain, from my point of view, this is probably an application-level problem. Not a DB issue. You app will encode data before sending them to the DB, and decode them while reading from the DB. ...

Comment: ... How to do that exactly will depend on your specific encryption algorithm and/or security requirements. If you use simple shared secret encryption, the encryption key could simply be stored on a configuration file *of your application*. Or even being hard-coded into it. If you need something more sophisticated, you might ask the user for the encryption key. Or you might rely on user provided certificate to obtain the key. Or use public-key infrastructure. It all depends on *your* specific needs.

Comment: I don't believe that requested solution of exchanging (hiding) key depends on encryption algorithm used, but however, thanks Sylvian for you effort.

Comment: My question is about strategy of implementing the solution for data encryption in multiple users web application (it assumes symetric key). It's not DBMS issue, nor there are specific needs; it's question like this one; http://security.stackexchange.com/questions/4575/encryption-strategies-for-multi-users-access-in-production-systems (there I found the solution as well - One common key, and it is encrypted by each user key)